# Refactoring plug-in for Visual Studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, refactoring, visual-studio-2003

Are there any free refactoring tools available for Visual Studio 2003?  [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper20/download/index.html) seems to require a license key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in a similar boat. Inherited a .NET 1.1 project tied to old third party components. I'm working on migrating it standard WinForm components so I can move it to 2005 or 2008.

Sadly no. There are free refactoring tools for VS 2005+ but none for 2003.

- DevExpress offers Refactor! Pro for
  $99, which has support for 2003.
- ModelMaker Tools offers CodeExplorer,
  also $99. With support for 2003.
- You've already discovered ReSharper,
  which is the most popular.

There used to be a few others but those are the only ones left.

If you want to experiment you could try SharpDevelop. Its an open source .net IDE with a lot of refactoring support built in. Version 3 has dropped support for .NET 1.1 but they still offer versions 1 and 2 for download as well. I've used it myself. If your careful you can set up dual IDEs. SharpDevelop for refactoring and general development and VS2003 for anything SharpDevelop can't handle.

**Update:**
SharpDevelop's refactoring support in older versions is very immature, it only supported function renaming. The latest version, which dropped support for .NET 1.1, has a number of useful refactorings.